# Should a development domain that is indexed better than the real domain be deleted or redirected if I want to re-use it later?

Tags: seo, google-search, redirects

I am a Web Developer and now almost nothing about server management.

I setup a test server for one of our project at **mypersonaldomain.com** so that I would have a permanent URL to send to my coworkers and clients. The website is hosted on a server I created using DigitalOcean.

Now my clients have sent me their credentials and I've setup the website on their server too, with the domain name **realdomain.com** pointing at that server.

**The problem :** Right now if you do a Google Search for "real domain", you find the link to **mypersonnaldomain.com** since it's publicly accessible and has been accessed many times, it's more popular than the **realdomain.com** and is ranked before.

What's the best way to solve this issue?

Can I remove the files from my own server and then ask Google ( https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6349986?hl=en ) to remove the search results for the old content?

Or maybe it's best to setup a redirection from the old one to the new one?

There are two things to keep in mind :

- I would like to re-use **mypersonaldomain.com** in the future, so I don't want it blacklisted or removed completely from the results in any permanent fashion
- I don't want **mypersonaldomain.com** to redirect to **realdomain.com** forever, since I might want to use it again for other things

Answer (score 2):

You can't endorse a site with a 301 redirect and somehow maintain it's status for use again later. That would lead to a situation in which people would be cloning equity by switching periodically.

Do more off-page SEO on the real domain. Change the content on your personal domain. Eventually Google will catch up and rank the more useful of the two higher.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any way to speed up this "catching up" process, by manually telling Google that it changed and should be reindexed?

Comment: Google will periodically re-crawl the page and update. Beyond submitting new URLs there's not much you can do. You can request URLs to be temporarily de-indexed if there's problems with an URL you don't want published.

Answer (score 1):

Take off content from your site, put a holding page and submit in google webmasters tools for re-indexing. Usually it gets updated in 1-3 days